# How to extract values from nested string athena

Tags: amazon-athena, presto, dbt

I have a string column with several key values embedded in the URL like

`xyz:\/\/\/search?terms=Hair+Salons&alert_type=braze_220720_pah_gr_thematic_salons_lapsed&braze=1&utm_medium=push&utm_source=braze_220720_pah_gr_thematic_salons_lapsed&pid=5495eb2b0bf7443608972f7f021036e7`

i want to extract values of utm_medium, utm_source etc in Athena, how to do that?

I have tried split_to_map but it fails because of duplicated keys in some URLs

Answer (score 1):

Athena has a couple of functions that can parse and extract parts of URLs. For example, if you want the value of the `utm_medium` parameter from a URL stored in a column called `url_col` you can do this:

```sql
SELECT url_extract_parameter(url_col, utm_medium)
FROM my_table
```

You can find all the URL functions supported by Athena here: https://trino.io/docs/current/functions/url.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using a few [string functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/string.html) to get the key/value parameters from the URL.

This assumes all the parameters follow the word `search?` in the URL.

Here is a working example:

```
WITH t AS (
    SELECT 'xyz:\/\/\/search?terms=Hair+Salons&alert_type=braze_220720_pah_gr_thematic_salons_lapsed&braze=1&utm_medium=push&utm_source=braze_220720_pah_gr_thematic_salons_lapsed&pid=5495eb2b0bf7443608972f7f021036e7' AS data
)
SELECT
    split_part(value, '=', 1), --"Key"
    split_part(value, '=', 2)  --"Value"
FROM t
    CROSS JOIN UNNEST(
        split(SUBSTR(t.data, position('search?' IN t.data) + 7),'&')
    ) as x(value)
where split_part(value, '=', 1) in ('utm_medium','utm_source')
```

Giving results of:
[image]

Then you could just add a filter to get specific values you need:

```
where split_part(value, '=', 1) in ('utm_medium','utm_source')
```

- position('search?' IN t.data) + 7) is giving us the starting point in the string where the key/value pair starts.
- split(SUBSTR(t.data, position('search?' IN t.data) + 7),'&') we do a substing using that starting point and SPLIT on **&** to split each key/value pair and give us an array.
- CROSS JOIN UNNEST(
  split(SUBSTR(t.data, position('search?' IN t.data) + 7),'&')
  ) as x(value) - the cross join unnest takes the array and now give use each key/value pair in individual rows.
- split_part(value, '=', 1) and split_part(value, '=', 2) now allows us to split each key/value string on **=** and return index 1 as "Key" and index 2 as "Value"